# Can a visual concept hinder an understandable navigation?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, landing-page

Anyone who has read anything about graphic design will know the strength of blank space as a compositional element, whether as a design itself, as a concept, or as a style, such is the case of the *minimal posters* we see on the internet. But these three elements, physical or online, are static, they don't require or promote any type of interactivity with the viewer.

Not only in graphics, but also in other fields such as architecture or painting, but this is far from the axis of this question.

| [image] |
| --- |
| ##### Design *Source [celestingraphics](https://celestingraphics.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/5-double-page-design-editorial-design-examples/)* |

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| ##### Concept | ##### Minimal *Source [designbeep.com](http://designbeep.com/2013/10/13/excellent-minimal-remakes-movie-posters-hexagonall/)* |

In web design, large blank areas often prompt the user to use a cramped menu or scroll to discover the actual content. But they usually contain a main visual deterrent, such as a slogan, a central logo, a product photo, video, or animation. What happens when the landing page is just a blank area with links around it and a logo at the bottom. I can minimally understand something at a conceptual level, but at a navigation level, I don't see it so clearly. There is no deterrent beyond the white area that forces the user to start clicking links that lead to another site or, even worse, hide new content outside the window. Indirectly, inside the page, the user never leaves the blank area.

| [image] |
| --- |
| [modernmagazine.com](http://modernmag.com/) |

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when the landing page is just a blank area with links around it and a logo at the bottom.

When the user sees a large empty space in a website, they'll probably assume an image didn't load correctly. Unlike printed content where you ~never come across unintentional empty space, in websites every pageload starts with empty space only, [usually for several seconds](https://web.dev/fcp/).

Other than that, you just placed your navigation at the only possible spaces where the browser/system UI can interfere with them and may cause missclicks. You *can* account for that with large enough paddings and such, but at this point it feels like your concept is thoroughly in the way of the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm not sure that the large, blank area causes the user to miss the top navigation so much as the one heavy contrasting visual element (the logo) pulls the eye down off the top nav, and then leads to a second nav that might or might not be the main nav (the hamburger menu suggests that it is). Everything about this design communicates that the top nav area isn't important. Even if the empty space were filled in, it's possible that it would still be missed.